# How to setup Semantic UI spinner in my code?

Tags: html, semantic-ui

Semantic UI link: https://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html
Here is Semantic code provided:

```
<div class="ui segment">
  <div class="ui active dimmer">
    <div class="ui text loader">Loading</div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I want to use loading spinner on Save and also for global(eg. form load). 
When action is performed, spinner should be disappeared

Here is my HTML:

```
<button class="ui positive button" id="btn_save" formaction="AddNewDriver">Save</button>
```

"AddNewDriver" is my servlet which is performing save and lot of code.

Please give simple solution and where should i add that?

Comment: you can use ProgressBar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar

Comment: your given link is not a solution